# python df.melt - two identical statements, but only one of them works?

Tags: python

I am using df_melt on two data frames, which have the exact same structure and the only difference is one of the variables. The df_melt statement works perfectly on one date frame, but I get "Syntax error: Positional argument follows keyword argument" for th other one.

My statements:

```
df_1 = df_a.melt(id_vars = 'location', value_vars['men','women'], var_name = 'gender', value_name = 'income') #working
df_2 = df_b.melt(id_vars = 'age', value_vars['men','women'], var_name = 'gender', value_name = 'income') #not working, receive syntax error
```

df_1 looks like this:

| Location | Men | Women |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TX | 87,000 | 70,000 |

df_2 looks like this:

| Age | Men | Women |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | 40,000 | 45,000 |

Any help would be so much appreciated!

Comment: You’re missing an `=` between `value_vars` and the list

Comment: Actually, neither of them work. I just ran them through a linter and tried passing them through the interpreter, and got the exact same error in all cases. So I'm voting to close the question as "not reproducible". If you can find the actual problem, please provide a [mre].

Comment: @wjandrea they both work for me (2nd one now that I applied fix from the othe r commenter)

Comment: @Ivy Well yeah, of course they work after you fix the typo, but my point is, the premise of the question is wrong: *both* statements have syntax errors. So in the future, make a [mre] to make sure that the code makes sense.

Comment: @wjandrea both statements work when I run them now, exactly as they are, so the syntax is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the first one works? It should encounter a syntax error as well.

Anyway, the issue is exactly as the error message says - you have a positional argument, one which is just a value provided to the function, after a keyword argument.

`f(a = 1, 2)` will fail because `2` is a positional argument here (that is, which argument it is is defined by its position) but `a = 1` is a keyword argument.

`f(1, b = 2)` is fine though because keyword arguments can follow positional arguments.

I think you made a typo - `value_vars['men', 'women']` should be `value_vars = ['men', 'women']`.

Comment: yes when I ran the first statement it ran perfectly, no errors. but htank you so much!!! I have literally been looking at that code for 15 mins trying to see if there was a difference but I missed the equals sign in value_vars['men', 'women']. that fixed it! thank you